# Getting the free version of scheduler DhtmlX

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, scheduling, dhtmlx

I'am using `DhtmlX` library, and it's works fine but this error appears:

[image: error]

The evaluation period is expired , when i took a look to [website](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/editions.shtml) , i saw a standard version, with `NuGet` i just find the commercial versions :

[image: nuget]

So how can i download the standard version in [website](http://scheduler-net.com/license.aspx)  because i am using `DhtmlX Scheduler` and i need its free version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no free version of Scheduler .NET, only a [30 days trial](http://scheduler-net.com/). However, you can get a free client-side dhtmlxScheduler http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml